# Unable to create a new project without error

Tags: android, eclipse

I have been trying to create new project since the one I have made refused to show ads. So I downloaded sdk9 which was apparently hidden but even though after I launched the eclipse on clean project i got lot's of errors anyway and i didn't even add 1 line of code. I restarted eclipse multiple times feeling that maybe this SDK9 screwed something up since it's seeing errors in a clean project. Also whenever I create a new project I get aapt.exe stops responding, crashing.

Comment: use Android Studio :-)

Comment: can you read [ask] ? Provide us more details...

Comment: most probably you are not able to import many classes due to which you are seeing these errors, can you kindly show code snippet or image of it, i believe you are having issue with R.java

Comment: @PankajNimgade yup, problem with R. and something. I have downloaded new eclipse, unpacked, i have downloaded SDK 5.0 and other version and then i run eclipse.exe and then i h've created "new android project" and after loading i had many problems, errors... its stupid, because its new project, zero changes etc... i other programing languages i never saw stupid programs like eclipse. Eclipse probably is the TOP HIPER ULTRA BUGGED program. Worst program on the world. I just wanna create new, empty, auto-generated project, thats all and i cant cause errors, and stupid .exe crash.

Answer (score 0):

it alright i understand how you feel it has happened with many, ADT has no need to install but it start from eclipse so it needs to be closed properly every time you shut it off as many resources from sdk is always referred.

the project which is giving you error clean it and make sure you import yourpakagename.R instead of android.R, as your resource reside in yourpackage.R it should be able to refer it from there. Well it's not the only issue with eclipse